# Applying Bootstrap 4's CSS classes to a Magento 2 theme?

Tags: bootstrap-4, magento2

I am trying to create a from-scratch theme for Magento 2.2.4, based on Bootstrap 4. I'm not using a parent theme such as Magento's Blank or Luma. The reason for this is because this Magento store is going to be part of a larger website that's going to be bootstrap-based, so creating a theme based on a customized "Luma" or "Blank" doesn't make sense.

I've successfully gotten bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js to load within my head tags. At this time I'm not looking to add any custom CSS that I've written myself; All I need now is pointers on the best methods to apply Bootstrap 4's built-in classes (most importantly the grid system, but also various form, nav, list, and breadcrumb classes eventually) to Magento 2's layout (xml) and template (.phtml) files to my blank, parent-less Magento theme.

Does this make sense? I'm surprised at the lack of helpful information I've found around the web, but I'm hoping you all can give me some direction. Thank you.

Comment: Just stumbled across this question when searching for something else but my agency is currently working on a client project that is exactly this. A completely bespoke theme which we designed entirely built in Bootstrap 4(.4). We literally started with a blank canvas and constructed everything in the theme from scratch. Out of interest, did you get very far with this? Reason you've got no answers is because your question is basically asking how to fully construct a theme using Bootstrap rather than shows you've attempted it and focuses on specifics.